# In Ubuntu, after I add a partition to /dev/sde, why don't I have a /dev/sde1 device?

Tags: linux, partitioning, ubuntu-9.10, udev

I'm using ubuntu 9.10 with kernel 2.6.31.  In addition to the boot disk, I have a software raid of 5 disks using mdadm.  One disk failed.  I removed it from the array.  mdadm --detail /dev/md0 shows:

```
0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
1       8       33        1      active sync   /dev/sdc1
2       8       49        2      active sync   /dev/sdd1
3       0        0        3      removed
4       8       81        4      active sync   /dev/sdf1
```

I installed a new disk in /dev/sde, but after I format it, I can't get the device /dev/sde1 to exist.

[image]

Then I reboot for good measure. After:

[image]

- I've tried fdisk, parted, and gparted.  I get the same behavior after formatting in all programs.
- The partition is not listed in /proc/partitions
- There are no strange messages in /var/log/messages
- All drives are listed in BIOS, including SDE
- My dmesg output is available here: http://pastebin.com/BX6ya3qx

I'd add the /dev/sde1 manually with MAKEDEV, but this uses udev, so I don't know what to do.  How do I get the /dev/sde1 device to appear?

Comment: inlined, ad made a tiny edit so that it makes sense that i did inline them

Comment: Thanks for your help Journeyman Geek.  I realized I'm actually using Ubuntu-9.10.  I'll edit my question once I have 10 rep.

Comment: edited for you - you can get rep, iirc, by ensuring your profile is filled up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS and it magically started working.  I can only assume it is a kernel or distribution issue.